# A metric with the name has already been registered | prometheus custom metric in nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, monitoring, prometheus

Getting metric has already been registered when trying to publish metrics from service. To avoid that I used `register.removeSingleMetric("newMetric");` but problem is that it clear register and past records every time a new call comes in.
Wondering what to address this problem:

```
export function workController(req: Request, res: Response) {


    resolveFeaturePromises(featurePromises).then(featureAggregate => {
        return rulesService.runWorkingRulesForHook(featureAggregate, hook.name, headers)
            .then(([shouldLog, result]) => {
                ...

// publish metric
                publishHookMetrics(result);
 // publish metric
                sendResponse(res, new CoreResponse(result.isWorking, result.responseData), req, featureAggregate, hook);
            });
    }).catch(err => {
        sendResponse(res, new CoreResponse(Action.ALLOW, null), req, null, hook);
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

```
function publishCustomMetrics(customInfoObject: CustomInfoObject) {
    const counter =  new promClient.Counter({
        name: "newMetric",
        help: "metric for custom detail",
        labelNames: ["name", "isWorking"]
    });
    counter.inc({
        name: customInfoObject.hook,
        isWorking: customInfoObject.isWorking
    });
}
```

stack trace

```
[Node] [2020-07-30T17:40:09+0500] [ERROR]  Error: A metric with the name newMetric has already been registered.
```

application.ts

```
export async function startWebServer(): Promise<Server> {
    if (!isGlobalsInitilized) {
        throw new Error("Globals are noit initilized. Run initGlobals() first.");
    }
    // Setup prom express middleware
    const metricsMiddleware = promBundle({
        includeMethod: true,
        includePath: true,
        metricsPath: "/prometheus",
        promClient: {
            collectDefaultMetrics: {
            }
        }
    });
    // start http server
    const app = require("express")();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(metricsMiddleware);
    const routeConfig = require("./config/route-config");
    routeConfig.configure(app);
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    return app.listen(port, function () {
        console.log("service listening on port", port);
    });
}
```

versions:

`express-prom-bundle: 6.0.0`
`prom-client: 12.0.0`

Answer (score 4):

The counter should be initialize only once, then used for each call. Simplest modification from code you gave would be something like this.

```
const counter =  new promClient.Counter({
    name: "newMetric",
    help: "metric for custom detail",
    labelNames: ["name", "isWorking"]
});
export function publishCustomMetrics(customInfoObject: CustomInfoObject) {
    counter.inc({
        name: customInfoObject.hook,
        isWorking: customInfoObject.isWorking
    });
}
```

BTW, I found this thread while searching a way to avoid the "already been registered" error in unit tests. Many tests was instantiating the same class (from a library) that was initializing a counter in the constructor.
As it is in tests, and I didn't need consistency over the metrics, I found an easy solution is to clear metrics registers at the beginning of each test.

```
import { register } from "prom-client";
// ...
register.clear();
```